# Best practice to translate hard coded strings

Tags: java, hardcoded

I have a finite set of strings for a product name. I also have a web service which sends one of these product names. However I need to send the product name in another format.

So I need a formatter/mapper somewhere before I send the message.

I COULD just make some hardcoded mapper class which takes in an argument and returns a hardcoded string like this:

```
String mapper(String productName) {
    switch (productName) {
    case "product1":
        return "prod1";
    case "product2":
        return "prod2"
}
```

However, I dont really like this approach, but I have a hard time trying to think up a better solution. Anyone have a better solution for this problem?

I'm considering storing the mapping in the database and then create a DAO for this mapping which instead of using a switch it uses the argument as key and then queries the database which returns the alternative product name, but I'm not sure if its really a better solution.

any thoughts?

*  EDIT ***

Forgot to mention this:

The original product names are currently stored in the database. I will need to translate these names without modifying the current code/table setup, i.e. I cannot edit the table and current classes, but I can create new tables/classes if needed.

Comment: You could use a hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the database is a flexible approach, giving you the opportunity to adapt the mapping at any time, without restarting anything. However, performance may be of concern in that case. If so, build a cache of the complete mapping table and set up a regular refreshing schedule for it.

Comment: Performance is not a issue in this case. I guess this is "the way to go" as it also makes it easier to expand on later, should there be added more products.

So a table with a foreign key to the original product names and of course the alternative product names should do the trick..

Answer (score 4):

How about using `properties` file having content like

```
product1=prod1 
product2=prod2
```

and your method..

```
{
   //initializer
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.load(...);
}

String mapper(String productName) {
   props.getProperty(productName);
}
```

Comment: I think this approach is the best solution, actually the problem is how to translate names, so i18n-like solution solves it easily

Comment: Sorry, but I should have mentioned that the current product names are stored in the database, so using a properties file is not an option.

Comment: Then I'll create a new table with the translations, something like (key,translation) or (key, format/application,translation) if you think you'll need more than one translation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enumeration (or set of integers) as ID for product 1, 2 etc.

Then use a dictionary/map/array/whatever or a get function to get the name (either "product1"  or "product2"). Do not use strings when you want to USE these types, becasue they tend to occur more than one time in your code and if you forget to change it at one location you get inconsistencies.